# functional pointer to a templated function in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

i have this functional pointer

```
auto max_or_min = (x== 0? std::max<double> : std::min<double>);
```

this caused compiled error.

What is the right thing to do?

The error is: error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter list

Comment: *"What is the right thing to do?"* Show us the error message.

Comment: [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) has several overloads...

Comment: so std::max<double> still does not work?

Comment: You can do it like     `using FPtr = const double& (*)(const double&, const double&);
    FPtr max_or_min = x== 0? static_cast<FPtr>(&max<double>) : static_cast<FPtr>(&min<double>);
`